# Using math.isclose function with values close to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point, precision

As we know, due to the binary representation of numbers, this expression evaluates to `False` (at least in Python):

```
0.2 + 0.4 == 0.6
```

In order to be able to check for equality within numerical errors, the module `math` offers `isclose`:

```
import math
math.isclose(0.2 + 0.4 , 0.6)
```

This last expression yields `True` as expected.

Now **why does this following expression is `False` again?**

```
math.isclose(0.2 + 0.4 - 0.6 , 0.0)
```

It appears that everything compared to `0.0` is `False`

```
math.isclose(1.0e-100 , 0.0)
```

Comment: I do: `math.isclose(x, y) or math.isclose(x+1, y+1)`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer can be worked out by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose).

> ```
> math.isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)
> ```
>
> Return True if the values a and b are close to each other and False otherwise.
>
> Whether or not two values are considered close is determined according to given absolute and relative tolerances.
>
> rel_tol is the relative tolerance – it is the maximum allowed difference between a and b, relative to the larger absolute value of a or b. For example, to set a tolerance of 5%, pass rel_tol=0.05. The default tolerance is 1e-09, which assures that the two values are the same within about 9 decimal digits. rel_tol must be greater than zero.
>
> abs_tol is the minimum absolute tolerance – useful for comparisons near zero. abs_tol must be at least zero.
>
> If no errors occur, the result will be:
>
> ```
> abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
> ```

You use default tolerances which means that a relative tolerance check is used. And the equation above makes it clear why your expressions evaluates false.

Consider the final expression in the question:

```
math.isclose(1.0e-100 , 0.0)
```

Plug these values into the expression from the documentation and we have

```
1.0e-100 <= max(1.0e-9 * 1.0e-100, 0.0)
```

I think it should be obvious that when performing a relative tolerance comparison, using default tolerances, no non-zero value is deemed close to zero.

For very small values you should perhaps use an absolute tolerance.

Or you should re-write the test to avoid comparing against zero.

Comment: mmph. I did read the documentation and noted that I could set the relative and absolute tolerances. But I somehow missed the default absolute tolerance being 0.0. Perhaps I should go to bed... Thanks David

Comment: For completeness, the [original PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/#absolute-tolerance-default) explains why the absolute tolerance is 0: *"The absolute tolerance required to determine if a value is "close" to zero is entirely use-case dependent."*