# Time optimization, how to replace round

Tags: python, performance, rounding

After making a profiling of my program, I noticed that the `round()` function is called slightly too much.

```
ncalls     tottime   percall  cumtime   percall  filename:lineno(function)
12615015   69.616    0.000    69.616    0.000    {built-in method builtins.round}
```

Basically, my program is doing too many iterations, and I'm using the `round()` method a lot because I have float numbers like 0.3 that comes out often. Moreover, python doesn't output exactly `0.3` but rather `0.29999...9997` (coding problem of float numbers).

However, I need quite often to use if / else statements with comparison, and it took me a while to find out that the wrong output of my program came from these approximation errors, and thus the decision making was wrong because python wasn't in the right `if / elif / else`.

Question is, how can I replace this `round()` to avoid both the precision problem and the time-consuming rounding?

Thanks!

**EDIT in regards to the tolerance comment:**

I don't get the hang of how to do it with a tolerance instead of a `round()`.

Partial code:

```
d = round(abs(number_1 - number_2), 3)

if number_1  <= number_2 and d < 0.3:
      do_this()
      continue
```

My problem is when d is suppose to equal 0.3 because I will sometimes get 0.2999...99997 and sometimes 0.30000...0000005 (for instance).

I don't see how to implement the tolerance, `0.3-d < tolerance` is good if I would like to check for equality, but not for inferior.
Any suggestion?

Comment: use a tolerance for comparing floats for equality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242593/when-comparing-for-equality-is-it-okay-to-use/2242600 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324893/using-math-isclose-function-with-values-close-to-0

Comment: Indeed good idea, should have thought about it...

Comment: If you're using `round` to try to affect output… don't do that. Keep the numbers as they are all the way through your processing, and use formatting at output time to format the numbers with whatever precision you want.

Comment: And if you're using `round` to try to test for equality… don't do that either. Use `math.isclose` (or `np.isclose` if you're using numpy).

Comment: You are calling `round` 12 million times. 12 million of anything will not be fast in Python. You should either redesign your algorithm, move parts of your code to C, or deploy an extension efficient at such calculations, such as numpy.

Comment: Also, if your program is doing a shitload of iteration over floating-point math, you really should look into numpy if you're not using it. For most problems like this (well, you haven't actually told us much about your problem, but guessing), you should get a speedup of somewhere in the 6x-50x range if you do it right. A lot more than just removing one of your float operations will provide. Or, if you can't figure out numpy or have too much code to rewrite, try running your code in PyPy instead of CPython.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the reply. Indeed I know that numpy is faster because of the implementation behind, but I am not yet familiar with all part of it. I do try to use numpy arrays as much as possible instead of list, but I'm not sure if that is enough and I don't really know what else I can actually do. I posted a more complete part of the program, and of the problem with 2 of my most called functions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380594/time-optimization-of-function

Comment: @MitchWheat In regards to my edit, since I don't compare for equality, would you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Mathieu Just using numpy arrays instead of lists may save memory, which may mean saving time because of caching and paging issues, to get the real speedups you need to replace loops with array-wide operations. For example, `for i, n in enumerate(arr1): arr2[i] = n**2` won’t gain much benefit over lists, but `arr2 = arr1**2` will be much faster (as well as more concise, and harder to get subtly wrong—it’s usually either right or obviously broken).

Comment: For your edit, `0.3-d < tol` is _not_ right for near-equality; it will be true for 23.0, for a start; you need an `abs` there. There are also subtle issues with tiny numbers near 0. If you’re not going to use `isclose`, you at least need to read the docs for it to understand what it does and why.

Comment: Meanwhile, you say you don’t know how to do near-less-than-or-equal—but that’s almost exactly what you wrote by accident: `d < 0.3+tol`, except for the issues mentioned in my last comment. And if you’re wondering why this is the equivalent of <= and how you’d get < instead, you need to think through what the equivalent of == is again.