# Time optimization of function for signal processing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, time-complexity, signal-processing

I have a program doing a LOT of iteration (thousands to millions to hundreds of millions). It's starting to take quite a lot of time (few minutes, to a few days), and despite all my effort to optimize it, I'm still a bit stuck.

***Profile: using cProfile via console call***

```
ncalls     tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    500/1    0.018    0.000  119.860  119.860 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.006    0.006  119.860  119.860 Simulations_profiling.py:6(<module>)
      6/3    0.802    0.134  108.302   36.101 Simulations_profiling.py:702(optimization)
    38147    0.581    0.000  103.411    0.003 Simulations_profiling.py:270(overlap_duo_combination)
   107691   28.300    0.000  102.504    0.001 Simulations_profiling.py:225(duo_overlap)
 12615015   69.616    0.000   69.616    0.000 {built-in method builtins.round}
```

*The first question, is what are the 2 first lines? I assumed that it was the program being called.*

I'm going to replace the `round()` method by tolerance comparison in my `if / else` statements, thus avoiding this time consumption. I would like to optimize further the 2 following functions, but I can't find a new approach.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

class Signal:
    def __init__(self, fq, t0, tf, width=0.3):
        self.fq = fq                                    # frequency in Hz
        self.width = float(width)                       # cathodic phase width in ms
        self.t0 = t0                                    # Instant of the first pulse in ms
        self.tf = tf                                    # End point in ms

        # List of instant at which a stim pulse is triggered in ms
        self.timeline = np.round(np.arange(t0, self.tf, 1/fq*1000), 3)

    def find_closest_t(self, t):
        val = min(self.timeline, key=lambda x:abs(x-t))
        id = np.where(self.timeline==val)[0][0]

        if val <= t or id == 0:
            return val, id
        else:
            return self.timeline[id-1], id-1

def duo_overlap(S1, S2, perc):

    pulse_id_t1, pulse_id_t2 = [], []

    start = max(S1.t0, S2.t0) - max(S1.width, S2.width)
    if start <= 0:
        start = 0
        start_id_S1 = 0
        start_id_S2 = 0
    else:
        start_id_S1 = S1.find_closest_t(start)[1]
        start_id_S2 = S2.find_closest_t(start)[1]

    stop = min(S1.tf, S2.tf) + max(S1.width, S2.width)

    for i in range(start_id_S1, len(S1.timeline)):
        if S1.timeline[i] > stop:
            break

        for j in range(start_id_S2, len(S2.timeline)):
            if S2.timeline[j] > stop:
                break

            d = round(abs(S2.timeline[j] - S1.timeline[i]), 3)  # Computation of the distance of the 2 point

            if S1.timeline[i] <= S2.timeline[j] and d < S1.width:
                pulse_id_t1.append(i)
                pulse_id_t2.append(j)
                continue

            elif S1.timeline[i] >= S2.timeline[j] and d < S2.width:
                pulse_id_t1.append(i)
                pulse_id_t2.append(j)
                continue

            else:
                continue

    return pulse_id_t1, pulse_id_t2

def overlap_duo_combination(signals, perc=0):

    overlap = dict()
    for i in range(len(signals)):
        overlap[i] = list()

    for subset in itertools.combinations(signals, 2):
        p1, p2 = duo_overlap(subset[0], subset[1], perc = perc)
        overlap[signals.index(subset[0])] += p1
        overlap[signals.index(subset[1])] += p2

    return overlap
```

***Explanation of the program:***

I have square signals of width `Signal.width` and of frequency `Signal.fq` starting at `Signal.t0` and ending at `Signal.tf`. During the initialization of a `Signal` instance, the `timeline` is computed: it's a 1D-array of float in which `each number corresponds to the instant at which a pulse is triggered`.

*Example:*

```
IN: Signal(50, 0, 250).timeline
OUT: array([  0.,  20.,  40.,  60.,  80., 100., 120., 140., 160., 180., 200., 220., 240.])

A pulse is triggered at t = 0, t = 20, t = 40, ... Each pulse has a width of 0.3.
```

`duo_overlap()` takes 2 signals in input (and a percentage that we will keep fix at 0 for this example. This function computes the id of the the pulse for S1 and for S2 (ID in the timeline array) that overlap one with another.

*Example:*

> If a pulse starts at t = 0 for S1 and a pulse starts at t = 0.2 for
>   S2, since 0.2 - 0 = 0.2 < 0.3 (S1.width), the 2 pulses overlap.

I tried to optimize this function by looping only on the ID in which they can possibly overlap (`start_id`, `stop`) computed ahead.But as you can see, this function is still really time-consuming because of the high number of calls.

The last function, `overlap_duo_combination()` takes N signals in input as a list (or tuple / iterable) (2 <= N <= 6 in practice) and creates a `dict()` in which the key is the ID of the signal in the input list, and the value is a list of overlapping pulses ID (comparison 2 by 2 of the signals within the input list).

Example:

> Input: signals = (S1, S2, S3) The pulse n°2 of S1 overlap with pulse n°3
>   of S2 and the pulse n°3 of S2 overlap with pulse n°5 of S3.
>
> Output: dict[0] = [2]  /   dict[1] = [3, 3]  /   dict[2] = [5]

The 3 pops out twice for S2 because it will be add the first tile `duo_overlap()` is called on S1 and S2, and the second time when it is caleed on S2 and S3.
I don't want to avoid duplicates since it's an information on how many different pulses are overlapping (in this case, 2 pulses are overlapping with the pulse n°3 of S2).

*Would you have any idea, suggestion, code or whatever to redue the time complexity of this part of the code?*

I am currently looking into PyCUDA implementation since I have a Nvidia 1080 Ti at disposal, but I don't know the C language. *Would it be worth to switch to GPU this inner function that doesn't take long to execute when called but is called thousands of times?*

Thanks for reading such a long post, and thanks for the help!

Comment: If your code is otherwise working without problems, it could better fit on [codereview.se].

Comment: @usr2564301 Oh thanks, I was not aware of that. I will post as well, however, a different algorithmic approach to detect overlapping pulse than the one described above could also be proposed. Thus it would be better fit on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you could speed up your `duo_overlap()` function by relying on numpy instead of performing all the loops.

You would like to subtract all values of the `S2.timeline` from the `S1.timeline` and compare the difference to the width of the signal. The following function repeats the `S1.timeline` (repeats as columns) and subtracts `S2.timeline` from each row. Thus, the row indices correspond to `S1.timeline`, the column indices correspond to `S2.timeline`.

```py
def duo_overlap_np(S1, S2):
    x = S1.timeline
    y = S2.timeline

    mat = np.repeat(x, y.shape[0]).reshape(x.shape[0],y.shape[0])
    mat = mat - y

    # End of S1 pulse overlaps with start of S2 pulse
    overlap_1 = np.where((0 >= mat) & (mat >= -S1.width))

    # End of S2 pulse overlaps with start of S1 pulse
    overlap_2 = np.where((0 <= mat) & (mat <= S2.width))

    # Flatten the overlap arrays. The first element returned by np.where
    # corresponds to S1, the second to S2
    S1_overlap = np.concatenate([overlap_1[0], overlap_2[0]])
    S2_overlap = np.concatenate([overlap_1[1], overlap_2[1]])

    return S1_overlap, S2_overlap
```

A quick speed comparison on my machine gives,

```
S1 = Signal(50, 0, 1000, width=0.3)
S2 = Signal(25.5, 20.2, 1000, width=0.6)

%timeit duo_overlap(S1, S2, 0)
# 7 ms ± 284 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit duo_overlap_np(S1, S2)
# 38.2 µs ± 2.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. That was exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. It works, while I'm still trying to figure out what it does.

Comment: Issue fix with `mat = np.round(mat - y, 3)`. I still have a hard time understanding what the `np.where()` returns

Comment: Sorry to bother you with so much comment ^^' There is definitely some scenarios in which the output of both isn't exactly the same. However I'm not sure which ones (my script makes a run on thousands of different signals and the output pandas df are slightly different)

Comment: Signal(87, 0, 200, width = 0.3) and Signal(62, 0, 200, width = 0.3) returns 2 pulse overlapping when they are not. Issue is still about the rounding of 0.3 but I don't find where :/

Comment: Signal(87, 0, 200, width = 0.3) and Signal(62, 0, 200, width = 0.3) are overlapping at zero and ~80, no? This is what your function is returning for me as well? Is that not what you are expecting? Why are you needing np.round()?

Comment: `np.where()` returns a tuple of arrays. The first array gives the indices of the rows, the second of the columns for which the condition is `True`. Check the last example on the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Let me know if it's still unclear and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Indeed they are overlapping at 0 and~80. I wonder why I didn't have that yesterday.. Anyway, I'm using the round because of many problems with the 0.3 value (sometimes I will get faulse overlapping because of the computed value is 0.299....997 instead of 0.3). For the np.where() I kinda understand what it does, and yet I have issues visualizing the connection between the pulse ID and the output. I'm trying to adapt the code, could you check this if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405024/square-signal-processing-research-of-the-overlapping-pulses-between-2-signals

Comment: Finally figure out that mat[i,j] is the distance between 2 pulses, rows being ID of S1 and column of S2. Still having a hard time to adapt it with my second issue of the second post...

Comment: The other question you mention seems to be removed. I hope you could solve your problems.

Comment: Yes it took me a really long time but I figured it out. I'm not using to doing program like that, and I wonder now if I can generate a N dimensional distance matrix to incorporate the second function testing the combinations in one. Thanks a lot for your help!